# Reading a file off NTFS/ext3/ext4 using parallelism to get span less than O(n)?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing

I am wondering whether I can speed up the reading of a `.txt` file using parallelism when the file is stored on a local hard drive in `NTFS` (Windows) or `ext3/ext4` (Linux). Is it possible to parallelize this task to get a span of less than O(n)?

For example, if I have a file of 8,000 lines and I want to count the number of `x`'s in the file, can I split it up across 8 threads to read lines `1-1000`, `1001-2000`, ... `7,0001-8,000` and join the results (ie sum the `x`'s)? I imagine that there is a bottle-neck with disk I/O, but I cannot find a good explanation as to why, or whether there is a way around having to read the file using only one thread with O(n) work? Is there a concept that I a missing?

We can assume that the file is on local storage as `NTFS` or `ext3/ext4`. Also, I am using Java's fork-join framework if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you correctly imagine that there is a bottle-neck with disk I/O. A "normal" SATA disk might have a BW (for sequential IO) of about 100 MB/s. Compare that with the arithmetic rate of a contemporary x86 processor core which might be somewhere around 5 billion instructions per second, assuming a 2.5 GHz clock speed and ~2 instructions per clock on "real" code, which might or might not be close to reality, but should be in the ballpark. So in the time it takes to read a single byte from the disk the CPU core executes around 50 instructions [*]. Unless your comparison routine is spectacularly inefficient, it's not going to spend 50 instructions per byte to check whether 'x' is present on a line. Add more cores via multiple threads and the ratio gets even more lopsided.

Secondly, since you're talking about a .txt file, if you want to split it up among several threads, how do you know where line 1001 starts? Oh right, you scan sequentially through the file and count the linebreaks. For parallel processing one usually wants some kind of indexed file format, so that thread/process #N can do I/O from the correct part of the file without having to scan linearly through the file from the beginning.

[*] It gets even more fun if you start thinking about random I/O rather than sequential. On a 7.2k disk a disk seek is around 10 ms; in that time the CPU core executes around 50000000 instructions!

Comment: Great explanation! You mentioned that parallel processing is better for an "indexed file" format. I believe the most common indexed file format is a database, correct? Out of curiosity, could a distributed file system be useful in any way?

Comment: I don't know if a database is the most common indexed file format. Depends on which field you're in, I guess. In scientific computing, a field which I'm personally familiar with and where parallel I/O is an issue, HDF5 and various custom formats are the common solution.